# convert xml to csv using xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, shell, csv, xml-namespaces, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to convert an .xml to .csv using xmlstarlet. My filename is test.xml. The .xml data is like this:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ws_export xmlns="http://ws_export.ws.localhost/">
   <Records>
      <item>
         <CodIO>02360236</CodIO>
         <DescIO>023608 SAP- Stazione</DescIO>
         </item>
   </Records>
</ws_export>
```

I've seen an example [here](https://www.joyofdata.de/blog/transforming-xml-document-into-csv-using-xmlstarlet/), but the .xml file in the example has id with progressive numbers.

I've tryed some bash command like this:

```
xmlstarlet \
    sel -T -t -m /Records/item\
      -v "concat(CodIO,';',DescIO)" \
      -n test.xml > test.csv
```

In theory it should produce a .csv file which has column "CodIO, DescIO". But it doesn't work at all, I'm making an obvious error in the bash syntax but I'm not able to pinpoint it because of my limited knowledge. Could you please help me?

Edit to add my desired output:

a test.csv file with the column:

CodIO, DescIO

Comment: Please edit your question and add your desired output (no description) for that sample input.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after an improvement in my xml-foo, I've come up with a bash that works and produces what I'm looking for:

```
xmlstarlet sel -N x="http://ws_export.ws.localhost/" -t -m "//x:item" -v "x:CodIO" -o ";" -v "x:DescIO" -n test.xml > test.csv
```

basically all I had to do was list all my columns name, and a separator with a correct syntax, and declare the WS action which I did not right in my first attempt.

Comment: You could also add the option `-T`, to make sure you only get text.  This might be needed if the data contains [special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Entities_representing_special_characters_in_XHTML:~:text=Because%20of%20the-,special,-%26apos%3B%20case) characters.